# maxZoom and User Input

Tags: leaflet

I want to limit the users max zoom level with inputs (muse scroll etc.) and buttons. In other words, I limit the "maxZoom" to -lets say- level9. But I still want to be able to zoom to level10 in special conditions.
When I set the maxZoom, it obviously does not let me zoom more in any way, so wht is my solution in this case?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For setting maximum zoom level :

**map._layersMaxZoom=15** (which sets the maximum zoomlevel as 15)

Similarly we can set minimum zoom level:

**map._layersMinZoom=2**, (which sets minimum zoomlevel as 2).

Another way of doing the same-

**map.options.maxZoom = 15;**

**map.options.minZoom = 10;**

Comment: That's the internal interface, the public way is through setting the options.

Comment: As @flup stated, the public way of doing this is via the options http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-options

Comment: It appears that setting these options via the internal method doesn't persist correctly. I'd only use the public options method.

Comment: Any limit is there in max and min zoom level

Answer (score 18):

You can set the map's maximum zoom level dynamically with `map.options.maxZoom` in those special conditions and set it back when you are done.

Comment: `map.options.maxZoom = 15;map.options.minZoom = 10;`

Comment: Note that if you're displaying controls, this won't update disabled/enabled controls to reflect the new values.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

L.tileLayer('...', { minZoom: 5, maxZoom: 15 }).addTo(map)

Answer (score 2):

If you're displaying the controls and you change the `maxZoom` or `minZoom` options, the controls won't be updated.  For example, if your min zoom level is 10 and the current zoom level is 10, the zoom out control will appear disabled even if you change the zoom level.

One workaround for this solution is to trigger a 'zoomend' event on the map:

```
map.options.minZoom = 9;
map.fire('zoomend');
```

You might also want to consider calling the `setZoom()` method if you change the max/min zoom levels in a way that invalidates the current zoom level.

Comment: Thanks, my controls did not update indeed. using the fire('zoomed') function they do.